# How can I get regular firefox on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

I must use vanilla firefox to use the latest [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl) add-on.

I'm accustomed to jumping through hoops like using alternative repositories or compiling from source to get vanilla firefox in Debian instead of iceweasel, but those repositories don't have arm builds and I doubt I can actually compile something that big on the physical raspberry pi.  Is there any way to find a debian arm binary of firefox.

Comment: Things seem to have moved on and with FireFox requiring "Official" signing of add-ons it seems that using IceWeasel may be your best bet to continue using pentadactyl.  in the GitHub [Issue 79](https://github.com/5digits/dactyl/issues/79) for that project is a comment from the github user *If* around 2016-01-10: *"Also: if you're using iceweasel and the package is installed into /usr/share/firefox, it will work because of a debian patch to stop requiring signing of addons in there."*

Answer (score 1):

Why you doubt you can compile something "that" big. There are people (including me) that were able to compile kernel and so on (approx 10 hours :).

If you don't want to do native compilation on your pi you can always use cross-compiler. I can recommend you linaro compiler (or being more accurate toolchain).

Comment: I actually meant the space needed would be bigger than the SD card.  I don't know why I didn't think to attach an external storage device for the compiling.